# dont know what script will i put

Tags: javascript, html

i want to have this result
`http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7291/11250276724_fc1f751dc0_o.png`

this is the pic that i want to become result

but i dont know the script can someone help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function myFunction()
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" id="bike">100<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="bike2">100<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="bike3">100<br>
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Equal</button>
      <input type="text" id="total">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

i just want an output that example when i check one checkbox and click the equal the total will be 100 but when i check two checkbox and i click the equal the total will be 200. and the total will display in text.

Comment: Can you please explain all of your question here. It will help us now and others in the future.

Comment: This is a very specific question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask  If you can make it more general and help people understand the specific issue you're having and what you've tried, you'll be able to get much more helpful responses

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want the "total" input to be set to the sum of the checkboxes, this should do it.

```
function myFunction() {
    var total = 0;
    if (document.getElementById('bike').checked)
        total += 100;
    if (document.getElementById('bike1').checked)
        total += 100;
    if (document.getElementById('bike2').checked)
        total += 100;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
```

Comment: `http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7291/11250276724_fc1f751dc0_o.png`      i want this result can you help me thanks

Comment: i just want an output that example when i check one checkbox and click the equal the total will be 100 but when i check two checkbox and i click the equal the total will be 200. and the total will display in text.  thanks

Comment: buddy your answer need little bit of corrections document.getElementById('total').value = total

Comment: @shadow Oops, my bad. I use jQuery for all things so I'm used to setting values in brackets! Thanks for that!

Comment: Note that this answer will work for the code you provided, however if you are wanting to be able to add many checkboxes with different values, an approach as suggested by Deniz would be a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change dinamically values of the checkboxes. If so, you need to control the values. Try to do my following sample. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m43WZ/

1. Add Jquery into the head. If you already have do not do this step.
2. Add the function. 
   each function is controls all objects that you defined. We defined call all inputs which has the checkbox type. And "is" function controls the cases.

**EDIT:** * Added a class to find only prices that I want to sum. So, if there are different checkboxes not to calculate, it will be a problem and will affect my total amount. In sample I added class as cbBikePrice to make it clear.

```
<pre>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    var total = 0;
    $( "input[type='checkbox'].cbBikePrice" ).each(function( index ) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        // This is checked checkbox !
        // Add the amount to total
        // Value is a string. So, you need to convert it integer (Numeric)
        total += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
    }


});
    // Show the final total value
    $("#total").val(total);
}

</script>
```

3. Html form.

```
     <form>
          <input name="100" type="checkbox" class="cbBikePrice" id="bike" value="100"><label for="bike">100</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="bike2" class="cbBikePrice" value="100"><label for="bike2">100</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="bike3" class="cbBikePrice" value="100"><label for="bike3">100</label><br>


<!-- These are not not price -->
      <input type="checkbox" id="bike3" class="" value="100"><label for="bike3">100</label><br>

      <input type="checkbox" id="bike3" class="" value="100"><label for="bike3">100</label><br>
<!-- These are not not price end -->
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Equal</button>
    <input onclick="myFunction()" type="text" id="total" value="0">
    </form>
```

Comment: i tried bro your code bro but nothing happen when i checked the checkbox and click the button nothing appear in the text.

Comment: Have you added the jquery into the head?

Comment: anyway bro in this i only have three checkbox right.. can i add more checkbox bro.. like ten checkbox... thanks

Comment: Yes sure. It will select and count all checkboxes. I've updated sample. See it again. http://jsfiddle.net/Qqq78/1/ Btw you're welcome.

Comment: can you help me for this too bro [stackoverflow.com/questions/20454432/popup-alert-can-someone-help-me/20454774?noredirect=1#20454774](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454432/popup-alert-can-someone-help-me/20454774?noredirect=1#20454774)

Answer (score 0):

Try this | [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LBckL/7/)

```
<form>
      <input type="checkbox" value="100" id="bike">100<br>
      <input type="checkbox" value="100" id="bike1">100<br>
      <input type="checkbox" value="100" id="bike2">100<br>
      <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="equal" />
      <input type="text" id="total">
</form>

function calculate() {
    var total = 0;
    if (document.getElementById('bike').checked)
        total += 100;
    if (document.getElementById('bike1').checked)
        total += 100;
    if (document.getElementById('bike2').checked)
        total += 100;
    document.getElementById('total').value=total;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro.. but can i ask you another thing... coz i will add another button and text in that code, example i want an output that when i the "equal" and the "total" will appear in the text... in the another button that called "same" and text called "same1".. i put a number that less than the answer in the "total" and i click the button "same" a popup alert will come up and says "its wrong" but when i put a number that equal or greaten than the answer in the "total" the popup alert will come up and says "good"

Comment: @ginoside021 I didn't get your question

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454432/popup-alert-can-someone-help-me/20454774?noredirect=1#20454774) check this bro